# Jupyter Notebooks Spark RDD split function - remove brackets

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter, azure-notebooks

I am taking some "columns" from previous RDD, and than want to split second element. Spark wraps it in brackets. how to put them in one line (unjagg them, so remove brackets)?
I have spent about 10 hours to find the solution... needs to be done without using dataframe.
thanks

```
separatedRDD =  extractedRDD.map(lambda y: (y[0],y[1].split(' ' , 1),y[2],y[3]))

separatedRDD.take(2) # get output

[(u'2014-03-15:10:10:20',
  [u'Sorrento', u'F41L'],  ############### those are brackets I am talking about...
  u'8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af',
  u'33.6894754264'),
 (u'2014-03-15:10:10:20',
  [u'MeeToo', u'1.0'],
  u'ef8c7564-0a1a-4650-a655-c8bbd5f8f943',
  u'37.4321088904')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a list, so you just need to flatten it by pulling its elements one by one (assuming the size will always be as small as 2):

```
separatedRDD.map(lambda y: (y[0], y[1][0], y[1][1], y[2])).collect()
```

Result:

```
[('2014-03-15:10:10:20',
  'Sorrento',
  'F41L',
  '8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af'),
 ('2014-03-15:10:10:20',
  'MeeToo',
  '1.0',
  'ef8c7564-0a1a-4650-a655-c8bbd5f8f943')]
```